# django-guardian get_objects_for_group

Tags: django, django-guardian

What is the best way to integrate row level permissions into all models, so that listing would cause a simple JOIN?

I wish to have a shortcut like this one to return me a queryset

```
from guardian.shortcuts import get_objects_for_group
get_objects_for_group(GROUP_ID, 'view_invoice').
    filter(status__in=[InvoiceStatus.Issued, InvoiceStatus.Created])
```

this call results into more than query